# How I can get All Network Interfaces(including that are not running)?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I'm using this code:

```
NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

the above code retrieving only the active network connections, I need of all. How I do this?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Management;   



    ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(   
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" );   
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = query.Get();   

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)   
    {   
        Console.WriteLine(mo["Description"].ToString());
    }
```

Edit:

to find all others ["Properties"] name, change the foreach like this:

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection) 
            {

                foreach (PropertyData pd in mo.Properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pd.Name);
                }
            }
```

Comment: good work.Thanks! :)
Where I can get more details on queries used in ManagementObjectSearcher?

Comment: google for wmi query. start from msdn or here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176998.aspx