# Get Windows VPN Interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, networking, adapter, vpn

I try to get ALL network interfaces, I see in the window with all network adapters.
If I use

```
NetworkInterface.GetAllnetworkInterfaces()
```

I only get the LAN-Adapters and Loopback. But I don't get the VPN Connections I configured. The VPN Connections are the thing that I need but I don't find a way to get them (even if they are disconnected).

Is there something similar to `NetworkInterface.GetAllnetworkInterfaces()` that gets the VPN-Connections?

Comment: Are you sure that VPN is active? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473301/how-i-can-get-all-network-interfacesincluding-that-are-not-running

Comment: Hi, I am sure that the VPN is inactive. I try to get all VPN Connections to show them in a list. The list shows all connections - connected or not. Most times it will not be connected. I hoped there is something else then WMI.

Comment: If you don't want to use WMI, then you should probably write about it in the question itself.

Comment: Hi, I checked the WMI-Method, but this also don't show the VPN-Connections. If I add a new one, the number of instances in the wmi class will stay at the same number. So this WMI class seems to be not the correct class, but I found no otherone that matches my requirements.

Comment: I've practically never used `WMI` myself, so I am of no real use with this problem. You may ask a new question with [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that pertains to WMI (just make sure that there are no obvious duplicates and obvious mistakes). If it won't attract enough attention for some time, then I can put a bounty on it, just write a comment to me here using [@username notation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Also, when you will ask a WMI question make sure that you have written your platform specification and how exactly you create VPN connection, because it may be of help to answerers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows VPN interfaces are stored in **Dial-Up Phone Book Files**.
All VPN interfaces created through the Network Connections utility in Windows, will be stored in a default .pbk file stored at (Windows 7/8):

*"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"*

This file contains plain text, and could look something like this:

```
 [VPN Connection]
 Encoding=1
 PBVersion=1
 Type=2
 AutoLogon=0

 <...omitted...>

 [VPN Connection 2]
 Encoding=1
 PBVersion=1
 Type=2
 AutoLogon=0
```

**1:** You can either read all content of this file and filter the Connection names with a RegeX like this `\[(.*?)\]`

Regex Example:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ListVPNConnections
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // VPN adapters are stored in the rasphone.pdk
            // "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"
            string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +
                          @"\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk";

            const string pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path), pattern);

            foreach (Match m in matches)
                System.Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

**2:** or use a framework like [DotRas](https://dotras.codeplex.com/).

DotRas Example:

```
using DotRas;

namespace ListVPNConnections
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // VPN adapters are stored in the rasphone.pdk
            // "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"
            string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +
                          @"\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk";

            RasPhoneBook pbk = new RasPhoneBook();
            pbk.Open(path);

            foreach (RasEntry entry in pbk.Entries)
               System.Console.WriteLine((entry.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope, I could help you.

Comment: I just found out when you have VPN connection with -AllUserConnection (all users can use vpn from login screen) parameter it's not stored in this rasphone.pbk due to msdocs its stored in global phonebook could not found it.

And it's shown only in network adapters.

So any idea?

Comment: Can we control any VPN want ?