# Get windows VPN adapters with -AllUserConnections parameter

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, vpn

I need to get all VPN adapters programatically with C#

It works with rasphone.pbk

Like in this answer: [Get Windows VPN Interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610379/get-windows-vpn-interfaces-in-c-sharp)

Problem i found is when you create VPN from powershell with -AllUserConnections (all users can use vpn form login screen). It's not saved in that rasphone.pbk
The connection is saved somewhere in global phonebook due to msdocs. I was trying but was not able to find it.

PS command i use to add VPN:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name " + VPNName + " -ServerAddres " + serveraddress + " -TunnelType L2tp -L2tpPsk " + L2tpPSK + " -Force -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -EncryptionLevel Optional -AllUserConnection
```

Any idea where could it be? Or any idea how to check for VPN adapters with this parameter? Maybe with WMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found out only possible way is to use powershell command

```
Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection
```

and return output of commands into your C# app

//EDIT

Found location of global phonebook. It is here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```